# Simple decomposition of MySQL table

Tags: mysql, decomposition

I'm not a great expert in the field of databases and MySQL in particular - studying, so I bit confused in terminology.

I have an internal database organization, which has got a new job.
One HUGE table products, categories, and heaps of different properties.
The properties in this table are repeated many times (ie, non-unique).
Each position - a single row of the table.

It is necessary to divide it into several small ones (do decomposition) to select a title, category, and properties in separate tables with unique content.

Most likely it should be clear what I want, but still give structure.

**1. The structure of an existing database**

MAIN TABLE

```
id int (10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT - (the unique ID of the position of the goods)
prod_name varchar (255) NOT NULL - the name of the position (non-unique)
prod_cat varchar (64) NOT NULL - the name of the category (non-unique)
prod_prop01 varchar (64) NOT NULL - name svoystva1 (non-unique)
prod_prop02 varchar (64) NOT NULL - name svoystva2 (non-unique)
```

**2. I would like to get structure like this**

MAIN TABLE

```
id int (10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT - (the unique ID of the position of the goods)
prod_name int (10) - to the entry ID (unique)
prod_cat int (10) - PH category (unique)
prod_prop01 int (10) - Foreign svoystva1 (unique)
prod_prop02 int (10) - Foreign svoystva2 (unique)
```

TABLE OF POSITIONS NAMES

```
id int (10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT - (unique ID names)
name varchar (64) NOT NULL - the name of the position (unikalnoe!)
```

**And the same for the table - category Prop01 and Prop02.**

Can this be done only with the help of MySQL?
If not, then tell me a general algorithm for solving this problem.
Thank you for your attention to this simple task.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you'll need to do something like this:

1. Add the new columns (using different names)
2. Populate the new columns and tables based on your current values
3. Drop the old columns
4. Rename the new columns to match the old names.

Comment: INSERT SELECT DISTINCT will also come in handy.  Look up INSERT in the MySQL docs and find the variant that works with SELECT.  SELECT DISTINCT finds unique records.

Comment: 4. do not remove the columns, but make them link to the new database tables.